# Android phone does no longer communicates with wearable: SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-wear-data-api

I suddenly lost the connectivity between my Android phone app and Android watch. This worked just a day ago.

When I try to communicate the message from phone to watch, in response to the

```
mGoogleApiClient.connect()
```

the callback

```
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult)
```

is called on my installed listener. The log from the ConnectionResult .toString method looks like

```
Connection failed 
 ConnectionResult{statusCode=SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED, 
 resolution=null, message=null}
```

The phone and watch are both physical devices. They are placed on my desk  close to each other and from GUI appears that Bluetooth is on and devices are paired.

The watch runs Android 6.0.1 API 23 and the phone runs Android 6.0.1 API 23 as well. The phone project dependencies are

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.0'
```

The watch project dependencies are

```
compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:2.0.0-alpha1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:9.2.0'
```

Which service update is required here? Should I update my Android phone, my watch, or my library versions in Android Studio gradle scripts? I tried to play with all three but so far without much success.

How to make sure this does not happens to the customer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Wear Error ConnectionResult{statusCode=SERVICE\_VERSION\_UPDATE\_REQUIRED, resolution=null}](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30171361/android-wear-error-connectionresultstatuscode-service-version-update-required)

Comment: Also maybe this answer will help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28480170/2384186

Comment: One other thing to consider, you are using the Android Wear 2.0 Alpha library. Android Wear 2.0 hasn't been released yet so this may just be a preproduction bug  (send a bug report?).

Comment: It started to work again after I lowered version numbers from 9.2.0 to 9.0.0. Kind of solution.